# Pillow installation error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to setup my Django variant (Wagtail) but have problems installing the required Pillow.

Background: Am running `Python 2.6.6`, in `virtualenv`, using Mac terminal to have shell access to domain hosted on A Small Orange, `no root access`, cannot use sudo commands

When i run

```
pip install Pillow
```

i get the below error:

```
  Downloading/unpacking Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-2.3.0.zip (2.4MB): 2.4MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow/setup.py) egg_info for package Pillow
  Installing collected packages: Pillow
  Running setup.py install for Pillow
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow/libImaging -I/home/clarayee/.env/env/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_imaging.o
    unable to execute gcc: Permission denied
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /home/clarayee/.env/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nCrvqa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/clarayee/.env/env/include/site/python2.6:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ArgImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/tests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/PIL

running egg_info

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

building 'PIL._imaging' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/libImaging

gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow/libImaging -I/home/clarayee/.env/env/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/_imaging.o

unable to execute gcc: Permission denied

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/clarayee/.env/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-nCrvqa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/clarayee/.env/env/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1 in /home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/clarayee/.pip/pip.log
```

Same issue as when I run easy_install. Will appreciate any help!

Comment: `unable to execute gcc: Permission denied` . Ask hosting provide to run your command for you .

Comment: ah, will do that and report back. thanks!

Comment: 1. You don't need to be root to install inside `virtualenv` 2. What does `gcc --version` show? 3. What is in `/home/clarayee/.pip/pip.log`?

Comment: 1. that's what I thought too. 2. tried to check version returns: -jailshell: /usr/bin/gcc: Permission denied

Comment: 3. pip.log says `unable to execute gcc: Permission denied

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /home/clarayee/.env/env/build...
Command /home/clarayee/.env/env/bin/python -c "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Priyank Patel was right... it's a server-side permission issue. Thank you all!

unable to execute gcc: Permission denied . Ask hosting provide to run your command for you . –  Priyank Patel yesterday

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you have gcc and python-dev installed

`sudo apt-get install gcc python-dev`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gcc python3.4-dev` for python3.4

Comment: `gcc` specifically was the key for me - you just presume it's there!

Comment: did this, and didn't help me. I'm on GCP with root access.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem (gcc failed, but no mention of permissions), but it was dependencies that were my problem. By the way, my task was to install Pillow on a raspberry pi, which is why those dev libraries were necessary. They may not be necessary for you. It was the python-imaging command that did the trick most, I think. Here's what I did:

```
# Add the deb-src for each deb in /etc/apt/sources list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev tk8.5 tcl8.5 tk8.5-dev tcl8.5-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging --fix-missing
sudo pip install Pillow
```

Sources:
https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/322
http://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/8490/ubuntu-install-problem-when-it-comes-to-pip
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105265/install-pil-pillow-via-pip-in-debian-testing-jessie

Answer (score 4):

In case this helps anyone else. This may be what the service provider did.

On CentOS I ended up having to install Python headers to fix the problem.

```
yum install python-devel
```

then

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: +1 This one got me twice! For Ubuntu, run `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and then installing `Pillow` runs smoothly, at least in my case: `pip install pillow`.

Answer (score 3):

Try running this in terminal:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Then `pip install Pillow`

Comment: hmm... tried it, still the same result `Cleaning up...
Command /home/clarayee/.env/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-eL8ahy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/clarayee/.env/env/include/site/python2.6 failed with error code 1 in /home/clarayee/.env/env/build/Pillow
Storing debug log for failure in /home/clarayee/.pip/pip.log
`

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute it in **root** directory.